# Output an index number and remove the path from file

Tags: c#

I wrote this code, it works but there are 2 features I'd like to implement and I can't find out how.

First:
How to add an index number before each song so it looks like this:

> 1. Song1
> 2. Song2
> 3. Song3

Second:
The output to file includes the path to the file. How do I remove it?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\Music", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);   

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                Console.WriteLine(FileName);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("E:\\songs.txt", (files));             
            }          

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();   

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in order to only write the name of the songs and not the whole path, you'll have to use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtensions`.

To write the index before every song, you'll have to switch to a for loop (to work with the index).

Another problem is that you're writing to `songs.txt` for every song, which is bad. Here's a code to help you out:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Admin\Music\Playlists", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine($"{i + 1}. {Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i])}");
    // Each line will be something like: Number. NameOfTheSong
}

// Only save to the file when everything is done
File.WriteAllText("E:\\songs.txt", sb.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that you have a problem with this line:
`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("E:\\songs.txt", (files));`

Because in every loop you are writting the file songs.txt

About the new features:

For getting the index, an easy way is to change the `foreach` loop by a `for` loop.

For getting the file name you can use `Path.GetFileName()` or [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(FileName); The output of this line in the console is without the path before the song name, but the path is present in the .txt file.

Comment: @KKP44 because you have a problem with `WriteAllLines`, you are writting the string array of full paths in every iteration.